# Windows Phone 8 downloading files from web

Tags: java, html, spring, windows-phone-8, mobile-website

we are doing mobile web application in java/spring and we run into problem with downloading files like pptx, xls on Windows Phone 8.

In HTML we have simple code like this.

```
<div>
<a class="attchLink ui-link" target="_blank" href="/rest/item/DOCID159636/attachment/presentation.pptx">presentation.pptx</a>
</div>
```

On all phones we tested this (iPhone 4S,5, Samsung Galaxy 4,mini, Windows phone 7) it works fine but on Nokia with windows phone 8 we are sometimes stuck on icon *Tab to open* witch is displayed after downloading file. PPTX file have about 500KBs so it could not be problem with size of the file, and again phone sometimes (15%) opens it.

Have anybody any idea if this issue is solvable or just bug on Microsoft side in windows phone 8?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you have missed to set the content size of the file in the http header for the download.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "download/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public HttpEntity<byte[]> download(@PathVariable("id") int documentId) {

         /* or how ever you access the content */
         byte[] content = this.documentService.loadDocumentContent(documentId)

         HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
         headers.setContentType( /* depending on your document */ );
/* -> */ headers.setContentLength(content.length); /* <-- that's the point */  
         headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test.ppt\"");

         return new HttpEntity<byte[]>(content, headers);
}
```

Comment: Response from rest api looks like `Status Code: 200 OK
    Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
    Content-Length: 791775
    Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
    Date: Thu, 28 Nov 2013 09:37:46 GMT
    Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
    Pragma: no-cache
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1` Its ok to last byte.

Comment: We have content length set and it still works only one time from 100 tries on same file...

Comment: We are adding this headers via @ResponseBody annotation, and they look fine ... I tried set them manually like in your example and it didnet help either...